# Jest cannot find imported module

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I want to test my route and I exported my app in server.test.ts file but I got this:

```
 Cannot find module './middleware/errorHandler.js' from 'src/server.ts'
```

app.ts

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

// Custom Error Handler
app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => {});
```

Error handler:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';

export const errorHandler = (err: Error, _req: Request, res: Response, _next: NextFunction) => {
  Sentry.captureException(err);
  console.log(`Errorhandler: ${err}`);
  return res.status(500).json({error: 'Etwas ist schief gelaufen.'});
};
```

server.test.js

```
import request from 'supertest';
import {app} from '../src/server';

describe('hello', () => {
  test('test it', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
    .get('/api/photos')
  expect(res.statusCode).toEqual(200)
  expect(res.body).toEqual({
    message: "Hello World"
  })
  })
})
```

jest.config.json

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>'],
  modulePaths: [
    "<rootDir>",
  ],
  moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
    "src/",
    "src"
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
};
```

What I am doing wrong ? I can normally start my server and it find my imported file but not in tests.

What I am doing wrong ? I use jest